# How to open browser and android at the same time and run the tests simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I have a test scenario that is as follows, I start the application on android using appium, then I need to open the browser to authenticate some things, right after that I need to go back to android. How to do this process ? I thought of using multithread .

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ioSampleTest {

    public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    //Elements
    String secondNewJob = "//android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout/" +
            "android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ImageView";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Nexus API 24");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); //DeviceId from "adb devices" command
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
        caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.isinolsun.app");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity","com.isinolsun.app.activities.SplashActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset","false");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    }


    @Test
    public void basicTest () throws InterruptedException {
        //Click and pass Splash
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.id("com.isinolsun.app:id/animation_view"))).click();

        //Click I am searching a job
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.id("com.isinolsun.app:id/bluecollar_type_button"))).click();


        //Notification Allow
        if (driver.findElements(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).size()>0) {
            driver.findElements(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).get(0).click();
        }

        WebDriver browserFireFox = new FirefoxDriver();
             try {
              browserFireFox.get("https://google.com/ncr");
              browserFireFox.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3>div")));

            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
                } finally {
                    browserFireFox.quit();
                }

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.xpath(secondNewJob)));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This is a sample code in java, I took the code from these sites [Tutorial Appium Java](https://www.swtestacademy.com/appium-tutorial/)  and [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/) , and set up an example to make it a little easier to understand what I want to do.

Note The code may not work, it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application launching WebView from your android application to as what you have mentioned, "authentication" before you can do anything to your app?

I believe Appium's ***set context*** is what you need, the api will let you switch back and forth from native to webview vice versa.

But if you are insisting to test thru appium and at the same time to desktop browser with selenium, then it's not possible.